# Group policy in Azure AD between two domains which have two way trust between them

Tags: azure-active-directory, group-policy

I have two way trust between two domains say ABC and contoso domain.ABC domain users can read and write contoso domain users but contoso domain users can only read ABC domain users. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no matter with group policy, you need to set authority in the ADUC. And the user of the contoso domain must be the member of domain admins group，account operators group，or administrators group. Or you can delegate the user to have authority to create/modify/delete.